# Why are my ints over and underflowing here?

Tags: c, initialization, integer

When printing the values of reading input from the user, the numbers underflowing and overflowing, and I don't understand why.

So I am going through the ansi C standard to just pick up c as a language, and I do not understand why this is underflowing and overflowing the first two values.

```
int c; 
 int nl, bl, tab= 0; 
  while ((c = getchar())!= EOF){
    if (c == '\n'){
      ++nl;
    }
    if (c == ' '){
      ++bl;
    }
    if (c == '\t'){
      ++tab;
    }
    printf("%d\t %d\t %d\n", nl, bl, tab);
  }
```

Comment: What made you conclude that your numbers are "underflowing and overflowing"??? What is "underflowing" anyway?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This here

`int nl, bl, tab= 0;`

Sets `tab` to `0`, but doesn't initialize `nl` and `bl` in any way. Thus it's undefined behavior when they are increased later. Try this instead:

```
int nl = 0, bl = 0, tab = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use it like this:
`int n1, b1, tab = 0;`

You do not initialize `n1` and `b1`. Hence the unexpected results.
Variables `n1` and `b1` are just holding some garbage values, that were on the stack, and you are working with these, in your example.
Maybe the comma operator does not do what you've expected:
see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

If you want to initialize them together, you can do it like so:
`int n1, b1, tab;`
And then:
`n1 = b1 = tab = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it right after posting lol, but just changed the declaration to this

```
int nl=0, bl=0, tab= 0;
```